# how to bind document which contains image to the json object in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am binding object to the json object.I bind all other properties successfully except document which contains image.

here is my code

```
json.Append(string.Format("\"Name\":\"{0} {1}\",", rp.Fname, rp.Lname));
            json.Append(string.Format("\"City\":\"{0}\",", rp.City));
            json.Append(string.Format("\"State\":\"{0}\",", rp.State));
            json.Append(string.Format("\"Country\":\"{0}\",", rp.Country));
json.Append(string.Format("\"Document\":\"{0} {1}\",", rp.Document));
```

in my Document object Content, ContentType,Name,FileSize ,Date,StoragePath
but on view page i got

> > Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string error

Comment: convert the image to a base 64 string and then append
 using (Image image = Image.FromFile(Path))
    {                 
        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
            byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }                  
    }

Answer (score 0):

convert the image to a base 64 string and then append

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(Path))
    {                 
        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
            byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }                  
    }
```

To Convert a string back to Image use :

```
 byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);  
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);  
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);  
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);  
    return image;
```

Also Please Check this URL for more info : 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/convert-an-image-to-base64-string-and-base64-string-to-image

Comment: thanks it is working properly.but what about view should i convert this string in to array or i can use it directly for showing picture